# How to programmatically change Mac's audio output device or invoke the system "dong" sound using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos

I have an app on the iMac written in Ruby, and it would give out alert sound using

```
puts 7.chr
```

(or it can play an mp3 file).  But the problem is that sometimes the Mac is changed to output the audio in System Preferences to the HDTV instead of the internal speakers, and the HDTV can be turned off sometimes.

So is there a way to either programmatically change the output device to the internal speakers, or play the "Dong" sound which is the one when the iMac boots up -- the sound that comes from the inside of the machine?

Comment: the boot sound only exists in the boot ROM, although perhaps you can find another sound/find it online, etc. also, if the output has changed, perhaps that's the user's intention? I wouldn't make any beeps if the user has turned off system sounds, redirected output, etc.

Comment: it is actually one of my utilities script... so the intention is that, I have a script that can give some alert sound, but I don't want it to disappear if the Mac is hooked up to the HDTV and the TV is turned off (usually won't keep the TV on 24 hours a day... but will keep the computer on all day)

Comment: I guess you will have to use ruby cocoa/macruby/python to hook up a native binding--perhaps someone here can recommend a Ruby gem for native sound output. In principle I believe what you want it possible using native APIs